# iOS: Need advice on using keychain, NSUserDefaults/iCloud for auto-login and account creation

Tags: ios, passwords, keychain, account

I'm trying to remove the burden of users having to manually create usernames/passwords in order to login to a web service, so instead I automate the creation of usernames and password upon initial startup of the app.

So I'm using the [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) to store passwords in the keychain

```
[SSKeychain setPassword: myPassword forService: @"com.xxx.xxx" account: username];
```

and generate UUID (for both username and password) using:

```
+(NSString *) GetUUID {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

I want a single user to have access to these credentials across all their devices, so I'm thinking of using NSUserDefaults and iCloud to store the username so that when the user installs a fresh copy of the app on a new device, their username can be retrieved from iCloud and they can gain access to their credentials using the keychain, which will grant access to the web service.

Ideally I want the following functionality

- Upon first login the application automatically generates a username/password
- The user won't ever have to type in credentials, but simply get past the automatic account creation part of the app.
- After installing/re-installing the app across any device they'll have access to their credentials in the keychain using the "username" stored on NSUserDefaults/iCloud

**So my problem is:**

- Would storing the username on NSUserDefaults allow another user to alter the NSUserDefaults plist on their phone to access someone else's account? (From my understanding it's a yes)
- Is there another way to store the username so that another user can't alter the plist and auto-login into someone else's account?
- I'm a little confused with the concept of the keychain, so from my understanding the Keychain is shared across the entire app (so like a central database of encrypted data for all users worldwide(?)), so technically if another user has access to your credentials (i.e. they know your username and replace their own username on NSUserDefault with yours) they can use this to gain access to your data. Is this correct? (I thought that the keychain was similar to Mac, where it's a unique secured storage to each user).

I usually understand concepts quite well but the keychain got me a bit confused. I've read Apple's keychain concepts explanation but I can't comprehend the concept of whether it's a central repository of encrypted data accessed by all users or if each user has their own keychain storage and no one can access someone else's keychain storage, even if they had their username/password.

Comment: Keychain is only accessible to your app from a single device. It does not sync via iCloud. Also, NSUserDefaults don't sync via iCloud, their counterpart NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore does. And it does that very unreliably, so it would be hard to tell a difference between first app install and install on new/restored device when KVS hasn't synced yet.

Comment: So does that mean that I can use a generic @"username" and @"password" as keys when storing the actual values to the keychain and simply retrieve these on each device? Then use these to login to the server?

Comment: @thanati well if you're using `SSKeychain` it's all set up for you.  https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain Read the readme on github, it's pretty self explanatory

Comment: @mkral thanks for the input! Yeah SSKeychain makes it much easier to use and I don't really have any problems with using it. But I did get a bit confused with the concept of keychains so I'm looking for clarification at that area. Anyway I re-read Apple's docs and Filip's explanation cleared up that issue.

Still unsure of how to sync the data across universal devices though, I'm currently looking into game center username at initial install.

Comment: personally, I think I would want users to re-authenticate when they install the app on a different device. As far as settings go, create a server that fetches settings when they login.

Comment: I'm also trying to build a system without having users to create account/login. So far it seems, I will not be able to support multiple devices. One Idea I still have in my mind is to encode the (automatically generated) account in a QR code and allow the user to scann it with an other device to transfer credentials.